# Update TFS Build Definition from Text File

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

At my company we are using Team Foundation Server 2015 and Visual Studio 2013.  Our build definitions use a xaml build process template.

Using "Edit Build Definition..." to make changes to the build definition can be extremely tedious and error-prone, especially if changes need to be made in many places, over several builds etc.

I have Community TFS Build Manager, which allows you to export a build definition to json.  It also allows you to create a new build definition from json.  What it does not appear to do, which I badly need, is to update an existing build definition from json.

Is there a way for me to completely define a build definition in a text file (xaml, xml, json, etc) and update an existing build definition from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply: No

Complexly: You can use [TFS API: Build Process Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx#buildapireference) to create an app to archieve this.

However, I would recommend you to use vNext build if you want to edit the defition via json. With vNext build, you can update the build definition via [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/definitions#Updateabuilddefinition) in json format easily. This API support XAML build defitnion too but it can only change few things for XAML definition.